# Powershell: can stdout be redirected to a PowerShell function?

Tags: redirect, powershell

I use vim and want to use it to mimic [less](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less_%28Unix%29) in Powershell. So I want to write a PowerShell function to wrap it.

Vim has a [less mode](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/various.html#less). To use it I just need to issue a command like this:

```
type somefile.txt | vim --cmd 'let no_plugin_maps = 1' -c 'runtime! macros/less.vim' -
```

However PowerShell function doesn't seem to have a way to let me *take* stdout from the pipe. Any hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked this around with a batch file (less.bat) like the following:

```
cmd /c vim --cmd 'let no_plugin_maps = 1' -c 'runtime! macros/less.vim' -
```

And you can use it like:

```
type somefile.txt | less
```

Note that if you also need to invoke less with the following fashion, you'll need a conditional testing for arguments in the batch file.

```
less somefile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

> However PowerShell function doesn't seem to have a way to let me take
>   stdout from the pipe.

Just a hint, as I don't fully understand how your pipe works.
In any event, do you know the ValueFromPipeLine* Decorations ?

```
function less {
 param( 
 [Parameter(ValueFromPipeLine=$true)]
  $input
 )
 process {
    ##concatenate strings here, or process whatever vim sends into the pipeline
 }
}
```

[...Related Question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9328777/valuefrompipeline-behavior)